# Is it possible to calculate how long it will take to reach Break Even Point if the information provided is only an ROI (Return On Investment) of 10%?

Tags: microeconomics

Is it possible to calculate how long it will take to reach Break Even Point if the information provided is only an ROI (Return On Investment) of 10%?

Only ROI is provided. If there is a way to calculate, please say so.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your investment is $x$. What does ROI mean? The money you get per period out of your investment (= revenue).

What does break even point mean? The point (here in time) where your total costs (here it is only the investment) are equal to your total revenue.

Therefore, the time $t$ at which the total costs are equal to the total revenue is the break even point, with $r$ being the ROI.

$$ costs = revenue \\
x = r x t \\
t=\frac1r$$

You can see, it does not depend on $x$, therefore it is possible.